# How can you run a shell script in Amazon EC2 Instance from nodejs project in my local machine?

Tags: node.js, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a script in Amazon EC2 Instance which triggers the execution for auto scaling depending upon an entry in property file. I am building a UI in my local which will update the property file and trigger a shells script.

The UI is planned to be built using Node JS, which edits the property file and triggers the execution of shell script. Can anyone provide some light on to how to accomplish this task? Correct me If I am following a wrong approach

Comment: If the property file is on the server, how is your local NodeJS application going to edit the file?

Comment: I want to accomplish that task, but not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your UI and your server will read/write a common property file. If so, you could consider using S3 for the location of that file.  Then the UI could update it, and the server could read it when it is updated.